# SSL Certificate + EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

Is there a way to associate a SSL certificate with an EC2 instance without the need for an ELB?

I'm using a cloudformation template to do this, and I already have my SSL certificate. If it is necessary to associate with an ELB, then why does it have to be done this way?

Comment: What, specifically, does "associate" mean to you?

Comment: By association I mean like this (Look at SSLCertificateId: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-elb-listener.html#cfn-ec2-elb-listener-sslcertificateid)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone that is looking to setup their SSL on EC2, and they have purchased their SSL certificate outside of AWS, you can definitely have it for a single EC2 instance.

There is a full tutorial on how to achieve this in a medium article https://medium.com/@adnanxteam/how-to-add-ssl-certificate-to-laravel-on-ec2-aws-18104cc036d1

Comment: Certainly you can, but that isn't the question you asked, based on your earlier comment.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't, in the sense documented here with CloudFormation + ELB:

> SSLCertificateId
>
> The ARN of the SSL certificate to use.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-elb-listener.html#cfn-ec2-elb-listener-sslcertificateid

This refers to an IAM-managed (or, presumably, an Amazon Certificate Manager-managed) SSL certificate, neither of which can be deployed directly onto an EC2 instance, because certificates loaded from those systems can only be deployed onto resources that are managed entirely by AWS -- CloudFront and Elastic Load Balancer.  EC2 instances are not managed *entirely* by AWS -- you have access, too, which precludes this functionality.

If you "already have" your certificate -- meaning you purchased it from a third party -- then your solution will be to install it directly onto the machine from which you are building the AMI that you're ultimately using to launch the instance in CloudFormation.  Installing a certificate directly on an EC2 instance requires configuration specific to the web server that's running.

If you "already have" your certificate because you obtained it through Amazon Certificate Manager (ACM), those certs are not usable directly on EC2 instances because ACM doesn't provide you with access to the private key -- that's locked away in the ACM infrastructure, [accessible only to CloudFront and ELB](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/faqs/#services_used).